# New to Angular, getting Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '$$minErr' of undefined when trying to run code

Tags: javascript, angularjs, http

I'm new to angular and I'm attempting to take data in a json object and fill a simple table with it. After googling my error, most people are saying that with this error, the url for my library of angular is in the wrong spot, but I'm fairly sure it isn't. Can anyone help me out?

Here's my code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.6.4/angular-animate.js"></script>
<body>

<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myAppCtrl">
  <table border="1">
    <tr>
      <th>Name</th>.
      <th>Email</th>
      <th>Office</th>
    </tr>
    <tr ng-repeat="x in items">
      <td>{{x.Name}}</td>
      <td>{{x.Email}}</td>
      <td>{{x.Office}}</td></tr>
  </table>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.6.4/angular-animate.js">
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);

app.controller('myAppCtrl', function($scope, $http) {
$http.get("testData.txt")
  .then(function(response) {
      var needsJSON = response.data;
      var processed = JSON.parse(needsJSON);
      console.log(processed);
      $scope.items = processed;
  });
});

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Here is the text document with my data if anyone is interested

```
{ "Name" : "Test1", "Email" : "test1@test.com", "Office" : "NY" },
{ "Name" : "Test2", "Email" : "test2@test.com", "Office" : "LA" },
{ "Name" : "Test3", "Email" : "test3@test.com", "Office" : "ATL" }
```

Answer (score 3):

You have wrong angular url, Please use the following code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.6.4/angular.js"></script>
<body>

<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myAppCtrl">
  <table border="1">
    <tr>
      <th>Name</th>.
      <th>Email</th>
      <th>Office</th>
    </tr>
    <tr ng-repeat="x in items">
      <td>{{x.Name}}</td>
      <td>{{x.Email}}</td>
      <td>{{x.Office}}</td></tr>
  </table>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);

app.controller('myAppCtrl', function($scope, $http) {
$http.get("testData.txt")
  .then(function(response) {
      var needsJSON = response.data;
      var processed = JSON.parse(needsJSON);
      console.log(processed);
      $scope.items = processed;
  });
});

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Anto is correct, you're using angular-animate and you need the entire angular library.  Also make your file a .json file and you won't need to parse anything